Unable to infer a schema exception when trying to integrate GraphQL with Abp
I'm trying to integrate GraphQL HotChocolate with Abp. When I set up my configurations and register the GraphQL Services the schema does not load and in the UI it throws an exception and Shows a label No Schema. When i checked the logs it throws an exception:

Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type reference
Input: IEntity graphql

Here is my GraphQL Project structure:

And here is how i configured my Abp Module in ContractGraphQLMoudule.cs
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(ContractDomainSharedModule),
        typeof(ContractDomainModule),
        typeof(ContractEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
        typeof(ContractApplicationModule)
    )]
    public class ContractGraphQLModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            var services = context.Services;
            services
                .AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddQueryType<ContractQuery>()
                .BindRuntimeType<ContractBase, ContractType>()
                .AddFiltering()
                .AddSorting()
                .UseExceptions()
                .ModifyRequestOptions(options => options.IncludeExceptionDetails = true);
        }
    }

And in my Host project i only added the GraphQL Middleware for the UI and add the ContractGraphQLModule reference in the DependsOn
Anyone knows what is the issue? and how can i fix it?
Thank you in advance
